# Find posts that were in a specific review queue

Tags: support, feature-request, review, late-answers

In [another Meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32239/595055), the OP wrote that posts in the Late Answers queue are "fun to read". Personally, I have never reviewed a post in this queue, partly because they get reviewed before I have a chance to look at them.

I'm curious to see these posts for myself. Is there a way for me to view all posts that *were* in the review queue, but got reviewed already?

Comment: in fact, I have suggested some ways to do this [in my answer to the question you've mentioned](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32239/several-users-are-gorging-themselves-in-the-late-answer-queue/32241#32241). Although they are basically the same as in Glorfindel's answer.

Comment: Oh, I see that now. I probably should have looked at the answers to the other question in more detail before asking this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this once you have [10k reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> #### Access moderator tools
>
> You now have access to various lists and statistical reports, giving you a broad overview of activity on the site:
>
> ...
>
> - The full history of reviews by all users in any /review queue

Another option is to use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer; [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1272816/late-answers) is a query which lists the most recent Late Answer review items up to last Sunday morning (SEDE is refreshed only once a week). Do note that some of these may be review audits.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I've never used SEDE myself - what does numberOfHits mean in your query?

Comment: It lets you choose how many results you want.

Comment: Here is a query where using a parameter one can choose which reviews to show: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1258387/recent-reviews-of-a-specific-type And a similar modification of your query: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1272909/recent-reviews-of-a-specific-type (I have mentioned both review history and SEDE in my [answer to the linked question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32239/several-users-are-gorging-themselves-in-the-late-answer-queue/32241#32241).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak heh, I didn't look at the answers there. Essentially, this is a duplicate question ...

Comment: I wouldn't really consider the *questions* to be duplicate. I'd even say it might be useful that this specific question was posted separately. (It is easier to find when posted in this way - rather than hidden in an answer to a post which is about reviews, but definitely has different focus.)